# Dialogflow Facebook messenger webhook - TTS response

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, facebook-webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I integrated my Dialogflow chatbot with Facebook Messenger and I was so far able to successfully send custom text and audio files from my node.js webhook.
The problem is that in order to send audio it must be online and I have to provide its URL. Something like this:

```
            {
                "payload": {
                    "facebook": {
                        "attachment": {
                            "payload": {
                                "url": "https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/bugle_tune.ogg"
                            },
                            "type": "audio"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "platform": "FACEBOOK"
            },
```

My main goal is to be able, based on a decision that I make, to choose whether to send the response back to Messenger as text or as text-to-speech of the usual text response.

For Example: if the user says hi and the chatbot should answer by "hello", I want based on certain conditions to be able to either forward the "hello" as text or to send it as a vocal message (ssml or text to speech).

Based on my search I'm kind of convinced that fulfillment payloads for facebook do not include the SSML type. If true, is there a turnaround solution for my problem?  Is there another way to send text-to-speech?

(The platform doesn't necessarily have to be Facebook, but should be feasible to integrate with Dialogflow)

Comment: Based from the [Facebook Send API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/#message)(the Dialogflow API calls Send API for integration) it does not support SSML. You can file a feature request about supporting SSML to Facebook Send API so it can be supported moving forward. See https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/. Also I can't see [dialogflow integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations) that supports SSML.

Comment: But doesn't google assistant support SSML? I wanted something similar to that but with text modality as well.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not familiar with the features of Google Assistant as it's not part of GCP. But either way you can file a feature request to the Dialogflow team to request the support of SSML or text to speech on the payload. See [file a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).